# bluetooth pi zero w

Tags: python, c, bluetooth, pi

I am trying to write a program on my pi zero w that will access the bluetooth and just do a scan.

If I write the program in C using the examples on the web I get no errors but also do not see any devices.

if I run hcitool lescan I get a list of devices.  So I know the bluetooth is working.

If I write a simple scan script in python I get this error:

```
import sys
import platform
import logging
import binascii
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner



`async def main():
    async with BleakScanner() as scanner:
        devices = await scanner.discover()
        for d in devices:
            print(d)


asyncio.run(main())
`
```

```
`Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/stryd.py", line 16, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/stryd.py", line 11, in main
    devices = await scanner.discover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 216, in discover
    async with cls(**kwargs) as scanner:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 126, in __aenter__
    await self._backend.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/scanner.py", line 191, in start
    self._stop = await manager.active_scan(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/manager.py", line 368, in active_scan
    assert_reply(reply)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/utils.py", line 20, in assert_reply
    raise BleakDBusError(reply.error_name, reply.body)
bleak.exc.BleakDBusError: [org.bluez.Error.InProgress] Operation already in progress`
```

Sample C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

#define HCI_STATE_NONE       0
#define HCI_STATE_OPEN       2
#define HCI_STATE_SCANNING   3
#define HCI_STATE_FILTERING  4

#define EIR_FLAGS                   0X01
#define EIR_NAME_SHORT              0x08
#define EIR_NAME_COMPLETE           0x09
#define EIR_MANUFACTURE_SPECIFIC    0xFF

struct hci_state {
  int device_id;
  int device_handle;
  struct hci_filter original_filter;
  int state;
  int has_error;
  char error_message[1024];
} hci_state;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hci_state dev_id;
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };

    dev_id.device_id = hci_get_route(NULL);

    if((dev_id.device_handle = hci_open_dev(dev_id.device_id)) < 0){
        dev_id.has_error = TRUE;
        snprintf(dev_id.error_message, sizeof(dev_id.error_message), "Could not open device: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

   // Set fd non-blocking
   int on = 1;
   if(ioctl(dev_id.device_handle, FIONBIO, (char *)&on) < 0){
        dev_id.has_error = TRUE;
        snprintf(dev_id.error_message, sizeof(dev_id.error_message), "Could set device to non-blocking: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    dev_id.state = HCI_STATE_OPEN;

    if (hci_le_set_scan_parameters(dev_id.device_handle, 0x01, htobs(0x0010), htobs(0x0010), 0x00, 0x00, 1000) < 0){
        dev_id.has_error = 1;
        snprintf(dev_id.error_message, sizeof(dev_id.error_message), "Failed to set scan parameters: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    if (hci_le_set_scan_enable(dev_id.device_handle, 0x01, 1, 1000) < 0){
        dev_id.has_error = 1;
        snprintf(dev_id.error_message, sizeof(dev_id.error_message), "Failed to enable scan: %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    sock = dev_id.device_handle;

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));
    
    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id.device_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), 
            name, 0) < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s  %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free( ii );
    close( sock );
    return 0;
}
```

num_rsp is always equal to 0.

I have updated bluez to the latest version nothing I write will work but the bluetoothctl and hictool will always show devices.

Comment: I can reboot the pi.  Verify that the bluetooth is powered on.  Then run my python script and I still get the busy error.  I can then run the c program and I will not get any errors but will also not get any output.  Finally I run bluetoothctl scan on and I see all the output.

Comment: the rfkill command shows everything as unblocked.  root@piBox:/home/pi# rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

Answer (score 1):

`hcitool` was marked as [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) by the BlueZ project in 2017.

Using the raw HCI commands is not good on a shared system. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369686/7721752 for explaination of the different levels of interacting with the Bluetooth hardware

I was able to reproduce the error with your Python code. Instantiating the `BleakScanner` and the `discover` command both start scanning. I think this is why `discover` was reporting an `InProgress` error.

To report all the devices found at the end of the scan:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner


async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)


asyncio.run(main())
```

To have values printed as devices are found (and exit early when the desired device is found) I did:

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner


async def main():
    stop_event = asyncio.Event()

    def device_found(device, advertising_data):
        if (
            advertising_data.manufacturer_data
            and 76 in advertising_data.manufacturer_data.keys()
        ):
            print("Apple product found")
            stop_event.set()

    async with BleakScanner(device_found) as scanner:
        await stop_event.wait()

    print("All done")


asyncio.run(main())
```